# How can you define a function who's return type depends on the value of its parameter?

Tags: types, ocaml

Let's say I want to define a function called `zero` that takes a string like `"f"` or `"i"` and returns the zero value for either float or int.

So we could do something like this (I have no real implementation, this is just mocking up what I want):

```ml
utop # zero "f"
- : float = 0.0
utop # zero "i"
- : int = 0
```

What language features in OCaml make this sort of thing possible? And how do you actually use these features to accomplish something like that? (I.e. can someome show/explain how to do that?).

PS: In just about any other language I wouldn't expect something like this to even be possible. But I think in OCaml it is! I think so because `Printf.printf` from the `Stdlib` does something very similar (similar in spirit, but a lot more complicated in its details). I.e. the essence these examples have in common is that, `Printf.printf "..."` also has a static type that depends/varies based on the value passed as its first argument.

I tried to understand how that works by looking at source code for `Printf` but it is a bit too complex and deep a rabbit hole for me to understand. I am hoping this simpler but similar example of the `zero` function above would allow someone to explain the essence of the solution without all the complexity of printf's 'formatting syntax'.

Comment: This is lacking some details about what you actually want to accomplish I think. If the function is as trivial as your example, if there's a finite set of types you need to support and if you accept that the information needs to be passed explicitly, you could just make separate functions for each type, say `zerof` and `zeroi`.

Comment: THe gist of what I want to accomplish is something like printf. I.e. there is step interpreting the value and producing something from that who's type varies based on the input. But implementing a whole of printf interpretation in SO answer would be too much. So I tried to boil it down to something 'as simple as possible' while retaining the essential quality of that. I agree the simplicity makes it hard to see the whole point of the exercise. That's why I added that note about printf, to give some idea of why you'd want to do something like that.

Comment: There are other implementations of printf that are purely functional and don't use the compiler magic to convert "%d%s" into a format string type. They can look for example like this: `print (Int |> Text " * " |> Int |> Text " = " |> Int |> Newline) a b (a * b)` and rely on function composition to create the type information.

Comment: @Kris `printf` differs quite significantly from your simplified example in that it's variadic and takes the types of those arguments as a sequence given as the first argument. Whether that is a requirement will affect the answers significantly. If you don't need it to be a sequence it might, for example, be better to use a first-class module or just a simple function instead.

Comment: @glennsl I'm sure you are right, because in general the answer to many questions is always 'it depends'. And if we simplify something a bit too much... Anyhow I'm actually quite happy with Goswin's answer which does pretty much what my 'simplified' example asks almost to the letter. I actually don't have a 'real problem' to solve at the moment. The question is more an attempt to break down understanding 'implementing something like printf' into smaller pieces. And the two answers I got so far really do help me a lot at simplifying it and breaking it down into understandable pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the format type from octachrons answer explains why `printf` can have a return type depending on the value of the format string I don't believe that is the right thing for the question. Mainly because the format string isn't limited to only one value. What should `zero "%d%s"` return?

So let me give an alternative using GADT:

```
# type 'a t =
| Int : int t
| Float : float t;;
type 'a t = Int : int t | Float : float t
```

The type `'a t` is a GADT (Generalized algebraic data type) where each variant has a different type. A function, like zero, can then have the return type depend on the type of the GADT.

You might be tempted to just write this:

```
# let zero = function
  | Int -> 0
  | Float -> 0.0;;
Error: This pattern matches values of type float t
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type int t
       Type float is not compatible with type int
```

Unfortunately Ocamls type inference does not automatically understand GADTs and needs a little help. You have to always annotate a GADT for the type system to understand what is going on. A GADT type must be specified like this:

```
# let zero : type a . a t -> a = function
| Int -> 0
| Float -> 0.0;;
val zero : 'a t -> 'a = <fun>
# zero Int;;
- : int = 0
# zero Float;;
- : float = 0.
```

Comment: Even i was about to ask the OP same question... is he Ok with a algebraic type ?

Comment: I was really interested in how Printf works, since it seems that the underlying mechanics of how Printf accomplish this kind of 'value -> type' dependency, I think that seems to be the right answer. If there are other ways to accomplish this sort of thing (maybe using 'first class' modules somehow, that would be interesting too :-).

Comment: Not sure which is the better answer here @octachron is more detailed about the printf mechanics, which is really interesting and the 'spirit' of my question. But this answer is much simpler and actually produces something much more like the exact (simpler) thing my question asked for. So, I decided to accept this one instead. This is also a great answer as the simpler example makes it easier to understand the essence. Both answers are really great/complementary but sadly I can only accept one :-)

Comment: I don't consider one better than the other. You should know both and decide which is better on a case-by-case basis. There is also a third option using function composition in case you build a printf style function. But that only works for additional arguments, not for returning a value like zero does.

Comment: "I don't consider one better than the other". Me neither, but SO wants me to choose just one 'accepted' answer.

Answer (score 5):

Having the return type of a function depends on the value requires the type system to be dependently typed. This is not the case of OCaml core language (the module language is dependently typed).

What happens with `Printf` is that the first argument of `Printf` is not a `string` but a `format string`. There is a bit of magic in the compiler to make `format string`s appear as strings in the syntax, but `format string`s are in a fact a Generalized Algebraic Data Type (GADT).

You can observe it in the toplevel if we know where to look. For instance,

```ml
open CamlinternalFormatBasics
let s: _ format6 = "%s";;
```

will print

```
val s : (string -> 'a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'd, 'a) format6 =
  Format (String (No_padding, End_of_format), "%s")
```

In other words `"%s"` is a syntactic sugar for `Format (String (No_padding, End_of_format), "%s")`.

In term of implementation, it is a bit simpler to look at a simplified version of format string with only `string` holes and literals:

```ml
type 'args fmt =
  | End: unit fmt
  | String_hole: 'inner_args fmt -> (string -> 'inner_args) fmt
  | Lit: string * 'args fmt -> 'args fmt
let s = Lit("Hello ", String_hole End)
```

Here, the value `s` is the simplified equivalent to "Hello %s" and  is of type `(string -> unit) fmt`. Similarly,

```
let s2 = String_hole (String_hole End)
```

(aka `"%s%s"`) is a value of type `(string->string->unit) fmt`. In other words, the type `'a` of a value of type `'a fmt` tracks how many strings are needed to fill all the string hole in the format string.

Since, the information exists in the type, we can describe the type of printf as: `'a fmt -> 'a` (without any dependent types). The function `printf` returns a function that requires as many arguments as there are holes in the format string before returning `unit`. And indeed, it is possible to write down such `printf` function:

```ml
let rec printf: type a.  a fmt -> a = fun fmt ->
  match fmt with
  | End -> print_newline ()
  | Lit (lit,inner_fmt) -> print_string s; printf inner_fmt
  | String_hole inner_fmt -> fun s -> print_string s; printf inner_fmt

let () = printf s "world"
let () = printf s2 "Hello" "universe"
```

This works because GADTs allow to express a finer relationship between variant constructors and the result type of an algebraic data types.

For instance, if I observe a constructor `End` in a branch of a pattern matching, I know that the type `a` was in fact `unit`, and I can return without doing anything.

Similarly, if I a see a `Lit(lit,inner_fmt)`, I know that the `inner_fmt` has the same type `a fmt` as its parent. In other word, it expects as many arguments as its parent, and I can print the string `lit` and go on with evaluating my format string.

And the really interesting case, is the string hole `String_hole fmt`, which tells me that my type is `(string -> $inner_args) fmt`. In other words, the parent format string requires one more argument that its children. I must thus returns a function that takes a string argument, print its argument before resuming the evaluation of the inner format string.

OCaml implementation starts with this idea and adds support for many hole types in the format strings.

Thus printf as implemented in OCaml does not require dependent types, but only GADTs.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks for putting so much effort in it working/writing all of that out. It will probably take me some time to digest, but that's exactly the kind of 'simpler version' of printf I was asking for. to try and understand the essence of the mechanics involved in it.

Comment: Since when are format strings GADTs? They existed long before ocaml supported GADTs? Where they changed when GADT support was added?

Comment: ""%s" is a syntactic sugar for ,,," so, do I understand correctly that the conversion of this notation using "%" sequences into 'Format' GADT is baked in the compiler (so the parsing of that 'expression' into a 'GADT parse tree' is done by the compiler rather than the stdlib? Or is it possible to implement something similar but with a different string syntax (i.e. can we design our own 'string embedded syntax' and write our own parser for that, or is the syntax just baked in the compiler?). Anyhow... maybe that might deserve a different / new SO question.

Comment: @Kris Yes, the compiler has some magic that parses string literals into format strings. It's not something you can implement in the language.

Comment: I suppose if we really wanted to, maybe we could build/use some kind of `ppx` to do the magic?

Comment: Not from "...%s...". There is no way to inspect the value of the string to form a type at compile time. There are lots of other ways to do it but parsing a "..." into a type can only be done by the compiler with magic.

Comment: I guess I don't really undertand ppx, but aren't they like 'full on' AST transformers? So they are basically full-blown programs that run at compile-time (outside/before the compiler). So they can basicallly do anything, including taking the value of the string and convert into some kind of a more elaborated GADT expression tree? (This is probably shooting a mosquito with rocket-launcher, but seems like if we really wanted to, it could be made to work)?

Comment: It is perfectly possible to transform strings into format strings with a ppx, but there is a more explicit solution:  use an extension node (`[%fmt "%d + %d = %d"] `) or an extension string (e.g `{%fmt|Hello %s!|}`). This option has the advantage to avoid all possible confusion between strings and format strings.  See https://github.com/Octachron/ffmt/blob/main/example/meta.ml#L29 for an example of such a ppx.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, format strings were reimplemented with GADTs in 4.02.0.